# How to apply .FindFirst method in VBA for MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a table named tblProduct with 3 fields, Product_ID (short text), Product_Name (short text), Sale_Unit (short text), Product_ID is primary key.
Then there is a form name frm_Product, with cboProductID as combo box, with the row source set to:

```vb
SELECT tblProduct.ID, tblProduct.Product_Name, tblProduct.Sale_Unit
FROM tblProduct
ORDER BY tblProduct.Product_Name;
```

Its bound column set to 1, column count to 3, column width to 0cm;4cm;2cm, there are then 2 textboxes, txtProduct_Name and txtSale_Unit.
Then I wrote the following code for the AfterUpdate event of cboProductID:

```vb
Private Sub cboProductID_AfterUpdate()
    
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblProduct", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs1.FindFirst "ID = '" & "Me.cboProductID.Column(0)" '"
    txtProduct_Name = rs1!Product_Name
    txtSale_Unit = rs1!Sale_Unit
    
End Sub
```

The code stopped at the `.FindFirst` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rs1.FindFirst "ID = '" & Me.cboProductID.Column(0) & "'"
```

if you put quotes around that expression, then you wind up search for a id of Me.cboproductID.Column(0), and I don't think that is the "id" your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead : Remove the Quotes around me.cboProdtID.Column(0)